# SSRS - ViewMode=WebPartList performance

Tags: reporting-services

I'm currently facing following issue regarding Report Manager. When I access it via

> `http://myrshost/reportserver`

the Report Manager loads almost immediatelly. But when I access it using following parameter

> `http://myrshost/reportserver?ViewMode=WebPartList`

it always takes about 15 seconds to load. What could be the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by setting IP Address in Web Service URL section of Reporting Services Configuration Manager to All assigned (recommended).